¿Cómo hago un ciclo for con un numpy.array en python?
estoy calculando las sobreoscilaciones de una onda, y tengo las amplitudes de la onda en un numpy.ndarray que es la variable wfm y quiero contar cuantos de los valores son mayores que el valor que se llama ruido, y me sale el error 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable alguien me ayuda por favor.
from statistics import mode
ruido=abs(mode(wfm))
sobreoscilaciones=0
for i in range (0,len(wfm)):
    if wfm(i)>ruido:
        sobreoscilaciones=sobreoscilaciones+1
print(sobreoscilaciones)


El error como ya te han respondido es que estás usando paréntesis, sintaxis usada para llamar a algún objeto llamable como funciones, métodos o clases, en vez de corchetes para indizar sobre el array, wfm(i) vs wfm[i]. No obstante, me gustaría agregar algo importante sobre optimización:
Itera directamente, evita indizar si no es necesario
No uses ciclo for in range para iterar sobre una colección indizable si solo necesitas obtener sus valores, usa un ciclo for in sobre el iterable, es mucho más legible y mucho más eficiente. Es decir:
for ampl in wfm:
    if ampl > ruido:
        ...

Otra forma de obtener lo que quieres en Python sería:
sobreoscilaciones = sum(value > ruido for value in wfm)

Vectoriza las operaciones siempre que puedas
La regla de oro cuando se usa bibliotecas como NumPy, Pandas o Polars es evitar en lo posible usar ciclos ordinarios de Python y aprovechar los métodos ofrecidos por estas bibliotecas para vectorizar las operaciones. No solo suele ser más simple, sino mucho más eficiente al estar implementados directamente en C y optimizados para esas colecciones.
Esto en NumPy se hace simplemente con:
sobreoscilaciones = (wfm > ruido).sum()

wfm > ruido aplica la comparación de forma vectorizada sobre wfm, retornando un array de boleanos:
>>> wfm = np.array([2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 0])
>>> wfm > 3
array([False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False])

np.ndarray.sum() simplemente suma los valores del array, teniendo en cuenta que True -> 1 y False -> 0.
Incluso puedes usar scipy.stats.mode() que está optimizada para arrays de NumPy:
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mode

# Datos aleatorios para ejemplo reproducible
wfm = np.random.rand(1000)

ruido = abs(mode(ruido)[0])
sobreoscilaciones = (wfm > ruido).sum()

print(sobreoscilaciones)


La diferencia no es trivial, no cuando se están procesando cantidades de datos considerables:
import statistics
import numpy as np

wfm = np.random.rand(10**7)


%%timeit

ruido = abs(statistics.mode(wfm))
sobreoscilaciones = 0
for i in range(len(wfm)):
    if wfm[i] > ruido:
        sobreoscilaciones += 1


8.69 s ± 101 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


%%timeit

ruido = abs(scipy.stats.mode(wfm)[0])
sobreoscilaciones = (wfm > ruido).sum()


1.11 s ± 4.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Nota: tiempos de ejecución medidos con IPython %%timeit magic command
